# Vuejs + Jest : "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a Vue file which imports a Vue file from node_modules. This file  seems to not be recognize as a vue file when imported and doesn't use vue-jest.

I tried to use an htmlLoader, but doesn't work either.

Here is the error I get :

```
path/node_modules/vue-loading-spinner/src/components/Jumper.vue:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<template>                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here is my jest.conf.js :

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue',
    'html'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/test/utils/styleTransform.js"
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.vue$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest',
    "^.+\\.html$": "<rootDir>/test/utils/htmlLoader.js"
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
  ],
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/(test/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost'
}
```

Thanks for your help.